# javascript and ajax to update the second drop dowm and the function undefined error

Tags: javascript

This is my php file

```
          <select name="scity" id="city_id" class="myinput" required           onChange="getMalls()">
          <option value="<?php echo $_POST['scity'] ;?>"><?php echo $_POST['scity'] ;?        ></option>
           <option value="">Please Select</option>
           <?php
             include 'include/allcity.php';
            ?>
            </select>


             <select name="mallname" required class="myinput" id="malls-list">

                      <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    </select>



                <script>
                 function getMalls() {
                  document.getElementById("city_id").value;
                    alert(hi);
                     $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "include/allmall.php";
                        data:'city_id='+x,
                     success: function(data){
                      $("#malls-list").html(data);
                       }});
                          }
                      </script>

                      <?php
                           alert(hi);
                            include 'mydb.php';

                               if(!$con) {

                                     echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
                                        } else {

                                       if(!empty($_POST['scity'])) {
                                          $queryString = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['scity']);

                                         if(strlen($queryString) > 0) {

                                            $querys = $con->query("SELECT mallname FROM mallname WHERE cityname = '%$queryString%' order by mallname");
                                            if($querys) {
                                               while ($results = $querys -> fetch_object()) {
                                                     <option value="<?php echo ($results -> $results["id"]; ?>"><?php echo ($results -> $results["mallname"]; ?></option>
                                                            }


                                                             } else {
                                                                echo 'OOPS we had a problem :(';
                                                                       }
                                                    } else {
                                                       // do nothing
                                                      }
                                            } else {
                                         echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
                                                }
                                            }
                                          ?>
```

There is another php file after the script tag where it is referring to.

First of  all I am getting an error that function is not defined. Actually this is for activating second dropdown on the value of first dropdown. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if its significant, but up top you have a lot of space between ? and >

Comment: There also seem to be missing a } before the last ?> and the <option></option> line also looks off.